# How to compare two files using spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming, bigdata

I want to compare two files if not matched extra records load into another file with the unmatched records. 
Compare each and every fields in both file and count of records also.

Comment: What is the structure of files?

Comment: It's CSV format

Comment: What are they schema? What is the comparing column?  Is there any constraint?

Answer (score 7):

Let's say you have two files:

```
scala> val a = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("a.csv").alias("a"); a.show
+---+-----+
|key|value|
+---+-----+
|  a|    b|
|  b|    c|
+---+-----+

a: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [key: string, value: string]

scala> val b = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("b.csv").alias("b"); b.show
+---+-----+
|key|value|
+---+-----+
|  b|    c|
|  c|    d|
+---+-----+

b: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [key: string, value: string]
```

It is unclear which sort of unmatched records you are looking for, but it is easy to find them by any definition with `join`:

```
scala> a.join(b, Seq("key")).show
+---+-----+-----+
|key|value|value|
+---+-----+-----+
|  b|    c|    c|
+---+-----+-----+

scala> a.join(b, Seq("key"), "left_outer").show
+---+-----+-----+
|key|value|value|
+---+-----+-----+
|  a|    b| null|
|  b|    c|    c|
+---+-----+-----+

scala> a.join(b, Seq("key"), "right_outer").show
+---+-----+-----+
|key|value|value|
+---+-----+-----+
|  b|    c|    c|
|  c| null|    d|
+---+-----+-----+

scala> a.join(b, Seq("key"), "outer").show
+---+-----+-----+
|key|value|value|
+---+-----+-----+
|  c| null|    d|
|  b|    c|    c|
|  a|    b| null|
+---+-----+-----+
```

If you are looking for the records in `b.csv` that are not present in `a.csv`:

```
scala> val diff = a.join(b, Seq("key"), "right_outer").filter($"a.value" isNull).drop($"a.value")
scala> diff.show
+---+-----+
|key|value|
+---+-----+
|  c|    d|
+---+-----+

scala> diff.write.csv("diff.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Daniel, Its very helpful to me.